# Updates are not showing and CSS is not working in Wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress

Recently I'm facing some issues in Wordpress website and `issue are:`

**Issues 1**: Updates are not showing properly in live page.

**Issues 1**: If any live page I'll edit and save on draft and publish then it's generate a pagename with some random number, example:
(live page url) google.com/about/
(Updated page url) google.com/about-273/
like this type.

**Issues 3**: After Updated the page if content will not showing in live page then I've been using a plugin for cache(lite speed cache) so that moment I purge all these cache at that moment in live page CSS will not work in that entire page and after that I just leave the website for sometime it's automatically fixed.

Anyone can please suggest what are the way to fix those problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check with your hosting provider that they do not have auto cacheing set for your website. Most Cpanels allow for you to control this from your client login.
For the random page numbering in the URL , you can control the post naming convention in the settings. Perhaps you have some other plugin overriding these settings like CopyPost or CopyDraft that is adding to the confusion. Can you list your active plugins as well as any screenshot(s) of the issue ?

Comment: Thank you so much @mergatroidSA 
Here is the plugins I've activated in website- 
1. Advanced Google reCAPTCHA 2. Change WordPress Login Logo
3. Codebulls Top Bar
4. Column Shortcodes
5. Contact Form 7
6. Contact Form 7 Shortcode Enabler
7. Contact Form Entries

Comment: 8. Contact Listing for WP Job Manager
9. Country State City Dropdown CF7
10. CSP Manager
11. CSS3 Rotating Words - PRO
12. Database for CF7
13. Disable Real MIME Check
14. LiteSpeed Cache
15. Logo Showcase with Slick Slider
16. Page Links To
17. Really Simple SSL
18. Really Simple SSL Pro
19. Redirection
20. Redirection for Contact Form 7
21. Revisionize
22. SVG Support
23. WP Contact Form Salesforce
24. WP Job Manager
25. WP Mail SMTP
26. WP Sitemap Page
27. WPForms Lite
28. Yoast SEO

Comment: You can try  an online cache checker like the one found here : https://cache-checker.com/  . Other than that I would suggest that you go through the process of deactivating each plugin one by one to see if they have an effect on your page updates but I would first try the host/server route.